# SharePoint 2013 Search Rest API POST request format

Tags: 2013, development, search, rest

I am hoping to save someone some time as I couldn't find anyone talking about this anywhere.

I am looking at the SharePoint 2013 Search Rest API documentation and decided to switch my GET calls to POST to clean up code and allow for more complicated queries I foresee having to write.

Looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx) article, I build the queries to send to `/_api/search/postquery`.

After building a query similar to my GET one:

```
{
__metadata : {'type' : 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest'},
'Querytext':'alan',
'SelectProperties': { 'results':['Title,PictureURL'] },
'rowlimit':5,
'SourceId': 'b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'
}
```

And solving [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/10/23/tip-handling-http-403-forbidden-when-querying-the-search-rest-service-using-the-postquery-method.aspx) interesting issue.

I am now getting an error:

> The parameter __metadata does not exist in method postquery

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct format for the Rest API POST Search Query is:

```
{
  'request': {
    '__metadata' : {
      'type' : 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest'
    },
    'Querytext': 'query'
  }
}
```

I found an example [here](http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) in the second image.